# use winkey for other software in win 10

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I want to set winkey +z as hotkey for third party software(specifically "Everything") in win 10.

---

when I press winkey nothing show in field ,and I remember it will show "Win" in win 7.
  I think the reason is the default behavior(show start menu) has priority. So, how can I finish this job? my ideas:

- use autohotkey(never used before,not know whether work) to set hotkey
- similar to first,but just remove default behave of winkey so I can use 
  I think the best way is just to get higher priority for winkey . Which way is best?how?

Comment: `#z::MsgBox, Hi` - that is how you can use Win+z to fire up Message box with `autohotkey`

Comment: sorry ,I don't get your mean

Comment: `#z::MsgBox, Hi ` - is the simplest script for [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) that assigning action (Pop up window that say "Hi") as hot key to `WinKey+z`

Comment: so the option is to use autohotkey to redefine my application's hotkey ? Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Since you said that it is "my software" then you can use [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to set `WinKey+z` inside of your software.

Comment: @Alex , not software develop by myself . I have edit the content.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to modify your keys, and AutoHotKey is probably the most well-known and is a reputable program. Please try the suggested solutions and then report back whether they work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search the web not find a perfect way to do this,maybe like someone suggest I shouldn't take priority over Windows(I do think Windows should offer preference to set its hotkey),so I make compromise to change my hotkey .By the way ,I don't want to learn using AutoHotKey for now.